# Linked List, insert node after tail

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

My function is supposed to either insert a **new node** after the given position or , if the position is tail, insert it after the tail and make the **new node** tail.

It works for inserting a **node** at a given position but it does not work when inserting after tail. When I run the code for inserting after tail I get a segmentation fault. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
ListNode *insertAfter(ListNode *argNode, int value) {
        ListNode *newNode = new ListNode(value);
        if(argNode != tail){
          argNode->next = newNode;
        } else {
          tail->next = newNode;
          tail = newNode;
        }
        size++;
        return newNode;
 }
```

Comment: You basically loose the rest of the list if you try to insert into the middle since you never set the `newNode`'s next node pointer to the node after `argNode`.

Comment: @FeiXiang thank you so much! I am new to this and you helped very much. It is working now. I also appreciate the debugging tip because I have never used that before!

Answer (score 2):

Let the linked list is below.

```
Node1 -> Node2 -> NULL
Tail=Node2
```

If you insert Node3 into the end.

```
Tail->Next = Node3
Node3->Next = NULL
So, the result is
Node1->Node2->Node3-> NULL
```

It's ok. But if you insert Node3 into the position after Node1.

```
ArgNode(Node1)
prev: Node1->Node2->NULL
next: Node1->Node3->NULL. Node2->NULL.
```

The problem is Node3's next position is missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct ListNode {
    int value ;
    ListNode *next ;
    ListNode(int v) { value=v; next=NULL; }
};
int size=0 ;
ListNode *head = NULL;
ListNode *tail=NULL ;

ListNode *insertAfter(ListNode *argNode, int value) {
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode(value);
    if ( argNode==NULL ) {
        if ( head==NULL ) {
            // initialize first node.
            head = tail = newNode ;
            newNode->next=NULL ;
        } else {
            // insert first node 
            newNode->next = head ;
            head = newNode ;
        }
    }
    else if(argNode != tail){
        newNode->next = argNode->next;
        argNode->next = newNode;
    } else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    size++;
    return newNode;
}

void printList(ListNode *a) {
    while ( a!=NULL ) {
        printf("%d ", a->value) ;
        a=a->next ;
    }
    printf(" size=%d\n", size) ;
}


int main() {

    ListNode *n, *n3, *n2 ;

    head =insertAfter(NULL, 10) ;
    printList(head) ;
    n2 = insertAfter(tail, 20) ;
    printList(head) ;
    n3 = insertAfter(tail, 30) ;
    printList(head) ;
    n = insertAfter(tail, 40) ;
    printList(head) ;
    n = insertAfter(n3, 35) ;
    printList(head) ;
    n = insertAfter(n2, 25) ;
    printList(head) ;
    n = insertAfter(NULL, 5) ;
    printList(head) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The output is this.

```
10  size=1
10 20  size=2
10 20 30  size=3
10 20 30 40  size=4
10 20 30 35 40  size=5
10 20 25 30 35 40  size=6
5 10 20 25 30 35 40  size=7
```

Answer (score 0):

before  `argNode->next = newNode;` insert `newNode->next = argNode->next;`. If not you're breaking the chain in the linked list because you are forgetting to attach argeNode->next value to the chain.